# Access - Assigning matching IDs from one table to another

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've been struggling with this problem for a few days now...I'm not that experienced at Access, so hopefully I'll be able to explain it properly for everybody.

A while ago I was tasked with creating a compliance testing database for my company's internal processes. Right now it's all done through Excel and is structured like this:

```
Compliance Test 01:

-------|Sample1|Sample2|Sample3|etc...
Item1  |GradeA |GradeB |GradeC |etc...
Item2  |GradeB |GradeA |GradeC |etc...
Item3  |GradeC |GradeC |GradeA |etc...
etc...
```

Here is the DB structure, more or less:

```
[tbl_ComplianceTests]
```

lngID_CT (linked to tbl_LINK_Tests_Items.lngID_CT and tbl_Samples.lngCT_ID)

```
[tbl_Items]
```

lngItemID (linked to tbl_LINK_Items_Samples.lngID_Item and tbl_LINK_Tests_Items.lngID_Item)

```
[tbl_LINK_Tests_Items] (many-to-many link table)
```

lngID_Item

lngID_CT

```
[tbl_Samples]
```

lngSampleID (linked to tbl_LINK_Items_Samples.lngID_Sample)

lngCT_ID (linked to tbl_ComplianceTests.lngID_CT)

```
[tbl_LINK_Items_Samples] (many-to-many link table)
```

lngID_Item

lngID_Sample

I would like for the DB to check [tbl_Samples] every time a new lngSampleID/lngCT_ID combo is created. It would then look in (tbl_LINK_Tests_Items.lngID_CT) and check for any matching lngID_CT's. Then, for the corresponding lngID_Item's in the tbl_LINK_Tests_Items table, look inside the tbl_LINK_Items_Samples and *create* the matching lngID_Item/lngID_Sample combination.

For example:

a) The user creates a Test01 in [tbl_ComplianceTests];

b) The user creates Item1 and Item2 in [tbl_Items];

c) Item1 and Item2 are assigned via a form to Test01. (I've done this bit)
So now [tbl_LINK_Tests_Items] has the Test01/Item1 and Test01/Item2 combo.

d) User creates Sample1, Sample2 and Sample3 in [tbl_Samples], which are assigned to Test01 via [tbl_Samples].lngCT_ID

e) Now is the tricky bit. As the user creates the Samples in the form, I need them to be automatically matched to all the Items over in [tbl_LINK_Tests_Items] that also have the same lngCT_ID. *Then* those ItemIDs are stored in [tbl_LINK_Items_Samples] with their corresponding SamplesIDs. So, since the have matching lngCT_ID's, Item1 gets matched with Sample1, Sample2 and Sample3 *and* Item2 with the same samples.

As always I appreciate any help, sorry for the huge post but I wanted to make sure I explained everything correctly. Please let me know if I can clarify anything for you guys.

Comment: To make the relations easier to grasp, would you mind including your post with a screenshot of your project's relationship window?

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, the issues have been solved!
h_ttp://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/1112787-assigning-matching-ids-one-table.html